# SQL Join help

Tags: sql, mysql

```
<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM threads 
                          INNER JOIN accounts
                          ON threads.author = accounts.id 
                          WHERE id = ".intval($_GET['threadID']));
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$title = $row['title'];

?>
```

What if I have a column named the same in both tables? (title) How does it know which one to get?
How can I tell it to get it from accounts table not threads without have different name on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an alias to fetch the column with a different name

```
SELECT t.*, a.title AS account_title 
FROM threads t INNER JOIN accounts...
```

If you only want to fetch the accounts title, list the columns from threads that you DO want

```
SELECT t.wanted_column, t.another_column, a.* 
FROM threads t, INNER JOIN accounts a...
```

Answer (score 2):

Just qualify it like you do in your inner join.

```
WHERE accounts.id = 'something'
```